# Javascript checkbox state change

Tags: javascript, checkbox, onclick

This is going to be straight forward for anyone who understands this language.

I have a set of checkboxes, which I am successfully detecting via Javascript on window load.

I now need to detect any change in these checkboxes (ie checked/unchecked) and call in a function to do something else. However using this snippet causes the test function to fire on window load, not onclick, and I don't see why.

```
//action for county
if (parent != "innerpost") {
county[i].onclick test(name);
}//if
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write

```
county[i].onclick = function() { test(name); };
```

Comment: For future reference, why do I need to use a function there?

Comment: A handler (that responds to events) is always a function. So when assigning handlers, you'll always be passing in a function